# CORS Pre-flight checks OPTIONS error from AWS Gateway API

Tags: next.js, axios, cors, aws-api-gateway, preflight

I am struggling to resolve a '403' error:
*'... has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status'*

Any advice on how I can debug or what I could be missing is appreciated

**Tests conducted thus far:**

My lambda function in AWS responds with the correct headers:

- OPTIONS CURL TEST: [image: CURL Options test]
- Copied failed axios command as **CURL** (cmd) from chrome dev tools :[image: copy failed cmd as curl from dev tols] - (this ***does not*** work in command line, curl responds with: 'curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL' )
- Copied failed axios command as **fetch** from chrome dev tools: [image: copy bad command as fetch]
- [Online CORS Validator](https://www.site24x7.com/tools/restapi-tester.html):[image]
- And postman response to prove without cors, the functions works:[image]

***Other info:***

- I have validated the url, x-api-key etc many times, and tried
  different configurations of the axios request, all result in the same response, see the following image of the axios request [image]
- A few images from APIGateway showing the requests and
  integrations:[image: api gateway console image 1][image: api gateway console image 2]

OPTIONS request/response in the browser (suggested by Quentin ):
[image: browser response 1]
[image: browser response 2]

**My Current lines of reasoning:**

- Maybe there is an additional security setting I need to define in my
  cloudwatch template?
- Maybe there is a bug in webpack with next.js / axios 0.27.2 / node 16.14.0 . - I have
  found a near- identical response mentioned [HERE](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4712)

Comment: You probably should look at the details (especially the request headers) of the OPTIONS request (from the browser) which fails and compare it to the request you are sending with curl to see what is different. You said "I have validated the url, x-api-key etc many times," but it sounds like you've only done that in your code and not in the request that is being sent by the browser.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for the suggestion. I will inspect and add a screenshot accordingly soon.

Comment: OK, so you've added the screenshot. Have you compared what it is in it to the curl request you made? Is something missing? Something that might explain why the server is outputting a 403 error? Some header that you are using for authentication?

Comment: hmm, that screenshot doesn't have the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header I'd expect from the code provided.

Comment: Good spot, indeed it doesn't. 
The CURL response replies with the expected headers, where as the OPTIONS request via  Axios doesn't. Given the Online checker also validates the correct headers. I beleive the problem is  with the Axios request to the server of the preflight checks, somehow..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254640/discussion-between-jamie-nicholl-shelley-and-quentin).

Comment: I'm getting somewhere following this link: https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/1786#issuecomment-1083483845
I will post an answer later if succesful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 403 error is due to the OPTIONS response x-api-key **not being expected by the web browser for pre-flight checks**

Once I disabled the global x-api-key required in the cloudformation template via:

```
Auth:
    ApiKeyRequired: false
```

The result as shown [here](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/1786#issuecomment-1226013902); on the console depicts OPTIONS -> API Key 'Not Required'
[image: Answer]

-The response succeeded!

In conclusion, api-gateway interferes with the expected preflight process via it's default copnfiguration.
***Be warned!***

There is however a snag outside the scope of this question, in that multiple people have report difficulting enabled ApiKeyRequired for POST and not OPTIONS. This is a cloudformation issue (Please see linked sources below for more details)

**UPDATE:**

In conducting further research, enough people complained March 2022 with this exact problem, a specific flag 'AddApiKeyRequiredToCorsPreflight' was then [added](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/2350).

Example [here](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/2a331b98994312a0ac5a0765ff98d458c91e9a5e/integration/resources/templates/combination/api_with_cors_and_apikey.yaml#L10)

Discussion Sources:

- [Defining CORS when ApiKeyRequired is true results in an OPTIONS method that requires an API key](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/1786)
- [Function specific ApiKeyRequired Auth property does not override the global API default](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/1514)